# Помогите, пожалуйста, разгрести знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение такое: "И(,) как результат(,—) затяжная депрессия". Правильно ли поставлены знаки в скобках (это мой вариант) или надо как-то иначе?
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Слово "разгрести" здесь как-то неуместно(

Comment: Это точно.

Comment: Вы бы лучше делали замечания тем, кто ни "спасибо", ни "пожалуйста" не пишет. Автор вежливо попросил, так чего придираться, а? Лучше бы ответ дали.

Comment: Все равно слово неуместно употреблено!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне больше нравится вариант: "И как результат - затяжная депрессия". Здесь инверсия подлежащего "депрессия" и сказуемого "как результат"

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил два варианта: 1.И, как результат, затяжная депрессия. 2.И как результат - затяжная депрессия. Нужен бы контекст для более уверенной трактовки

Comment: В варианте 1. после "И" я не стал бы ставить запятую, чтобы не было разночтения между вариантами 1. и 2. Вариант 1. я счёл бы допустимым. Но более правилен (в данном случае!) вариант 2.: по смыслу в приведённом примере требуется тире, потому что "затяжная депрессия" - весьма  существенное недомогание, а если бы итогом стало "...ьтат,вскочил чирей", тут можно было бы ограничиться запятой. Различие между тире и запятой очень субъективно: помимо сущности недомоганий (серьёзных и несущественных) играет роль и экспрессия выражения чувств говорящего(это что: комментарий или ироническое отступление?